# Can you script publishing a GP service?

Tags: python, arcgis-server, geoprocessing, rest, arcgis-10.1

I have a geoprocessing service in ArcGIS for Server 10.1.

I would like to share this service with a number of external organisations that also have ArcGIS Server 10.1.
i.e I dont want them hitting my service, but for them to have the ability to easily re-publish the service at their end.

Ideally, I would like to bundle this into a simple installer, which prompts end-user for some admin credentials to ArcGIS Server, and then makes use of a python script to publish the service via the new [ArcGIS Server Administration API.](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//0154000005rw000000)

However - To publish a GP service, the [help states:](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/A_quick_tour_of_publishing_a_geoprocessing_service/0154000004sz000000/)

> To publish a geoprocessing service, you need a result in the Results
>   window

I therefore can't think how an installer would be able to publish a GP service from a python script, as sounds like it is restricted to being published from within ArcGIS for Desktop.

I also believe that it is not possible to achieve publishing a GP service [from a GP package](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00570000004p000000) either.

My question is, are my assumptions right, and **what would be the best workflow for me to share my GP service, so that my end-users can publish it to a GP service in the simplest approach possible.**

i.e. I want to avoid any human error, permission issues, and minimise the time and effort it would take for the end-users to publish the service seamlessly to their ArcGIS for Server.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll be able to in 10.1 SP1. When you run a geoprocessing tool in Python, its return value is a result object. There will be a new [`arcpy.CreateGPSDraft`](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#/CreateGPSDDraft/018v0000008z000000/) function what accepts these result objects and from there the workflow from Python will be [exactly the same as it is with map services now](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//00s30000006q000000).

Comment: Thanks Jason. Lightning fast response! My deadline will be after SP1 anyhow.  Thanks